# Spring reactive security using JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, jwt

I am trying for reactive security using JWT.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private WebAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private ServerSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = { "/login/**", "/logout/**", "/register/**", "/authorize/**",
            "/favicon.ico", };

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.addFilterBefore(webFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.HTTP_BASIC);
        return http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> {
            return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            });
        }).accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> {
            return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            });
        }).and().csrf().disable().formLogin().disable()

                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance()).authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll().pathMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated().and().build();
    }

    /*
     * @Bean public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { return new
     * BCryptPasswordEncoder(); }
     */

    @Bean
    public PBKDF2Encoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new PBKDF2Encoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationWebFilter webFilter() {
        AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager);
        authenticationWebFilter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(tokenAuthenticationConverter());
        authenticationWebFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(serverWebExchangeMatcher());
        authenticationWebFilter.setSecurityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance());
        return authenticationWebFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerWebExchangeMatcher serverWebExchangeMatcher() {
        return exchange -> {
            Mono<ServerHttpRequest> request = Mono.just(exchange).map(ServerWebExchange::getRequest);
            return request.map(ServerHttpRequest::getHeaders).filter(h -> h.containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))
                    .flatMap($ -> ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match())
                    .switchIfEmpty(ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.notMatch());
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerAuthenticationConverter tokenAuthenticationConverter() {
        return exchange -> Mono.justOrEmpty(exchange).map(e -> getTokenFromRequest(e))
                .filter(token -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(token)).map(token -> getAuthentication(token));
    }

    private String getTokenFromRequest(ServerWebExchange swe) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = swe.getRequest();
        String authHeader = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);
            return authToken;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(String token) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token, token);
    }

}
```

Here, If I access any protected URL using the token, the calls are going to tokenAuthenticationConverter() and getting below error when the method getAuthentication gets executed.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No provider found for class org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.lambda$authenticate$5(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/v1/user/1" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.lambda$authenticate$5(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.3.RELEASE.jar:5.3.3.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4219) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onComplete(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:104) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:141) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2344) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2344) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2344) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:112) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2344) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:184) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onComplete(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:104) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:357) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:222) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollectList.java:72) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.drain(FluxFilterWhen.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterWhen.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:267) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:225) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.request(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterWhen.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onSubscribe(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:69) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:161) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceWebFilter$MonoWebFilterTrace.subscribe(TraceWebFilter.java:165) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.6.RELEASE.jar:3.3.6.RELEASE]
```

Not sure what is wrong with that?

Also, I am setting userId and orgId in the token. Trying to get the token as follows in the request handler.

```
@Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    protected JwtClaim retrieveClaimFromRequest(ServerRequest request) {
        String token = retrieveTokenFromRequest(request);
        return new JwtClaim(jwtUtil.getOrgId(token), jwtUtil.getUserId(token));
    }

    private String retrieveTokenFromRequest(ServerRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.headers().firstHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);
            return authToken;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The above code gets executed where ever I need userId or orgId of the logged in user.
Is this a correct approach?

Comment: i suggest you look into the official documentation for how to customize JWT handling https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#webflux-oauth2resourceserver-jwt-sansboot instead of trying to write a filter, when there is already one to use

Comment: If you want to create your custom Authorization and Authentication JWT based take a look at this: https://github.com/soasada/kotlin-coroutines-webflux-security (is the implementation of Spring Security with Spring Webflux, in kotlin but is the same for Java)

Comment: @Nico, I dont see sample to get the custom claim on controller. I am setting 2 claims in token and need the same in the handler.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf, It needs jwk-set-uri. I dont have a separate AuthServer. I am just looking for something similar Spring session based security using JWT.

Comment: I didn't understand anything... you want to issue a session from a token, without checking its integrity?

Comment: @ThomasAndolf, I dont want to maintain a separate auth server. It should be part of my application similar to spring session based security.

Comment: I want to use token but dont want to maintain a separate auth server. This can be done similar to my example. But, your documentation link expects to maintain a separate auth server.

Comment: I had a problem similar to this that was caused by me inadvertently omitting the protocol ("https://") from the start of the `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri` uri.